# Notebook with a WindowOpacity too small becomes "click-through" for mouse

Tags: front-end, opacity

I created a notebook and was manipulating its `WindowOpacity` option:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
Manipulate[SetOptions[nb, WindowOpacity -> op], {{op, .3}, 0, 1}]
```

It works fine as a half-transparent window when the option has a value not too small, say `0.3` (Have written something in `nb` to make it more prominent against the web brower window behind):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when the value of the option is less than a certain threshold (in my case `0.004`), the `nb` window seems to be "click-through" for mouse, eventhough it should be still in place in front of the web brower window:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**The question:** Is this "click-through" behavior a feature or a bug-like thing? And why such a nonzero threshold?

ps. My environment is *Windows 7* (x64) and *Mathematica* 8.0.4.

Comment: Behavior confirmed in version 7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Same in version 8 on XP Pro SP3.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for edit. This is not the only issue I encountered about transparency things, it deserves a tag.

Comment: Confirmed on Mac OSX Lion, V 8.0.4.

Comment: On my v8/Win7-64 it happens around an opacity of 0.003, not 0.3.

Comment: Might this actually be a safety feature? If you could activate something by pressing a near invisible button while the user thinks he's pressing another button that would be a kind of an exploit.

Comment: In v8 on Win7-64 the threshold is 1/255. At 1/256 the click-through occurs. I assume window opacity is stored in an 8 bit alpha channel and therefore any opacity less than 1/255 corresponds to perfect transparency. As @SjoerdC.deVries says, one wouldn't expect a transparent window to intercept clicks for security reasons.

Comment: @SimonWoods 8bit alpha channel sounds really making sense! As for security reasons, I think it is always possible to achieve similar effects with `Overlay`/`EventHandler`/etc.

Comment: @SimonWoods Would you consider post [your comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9345/notebook-with-a-windowopacity-too-small-becomes-click-through-for-mouse#comment27001_9345) as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the code to look at the reciprocal of the opacity:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
Manipulate[SetOptions[nb, WindowOpacity -> 1/op]; 1/op, {{op, 1}, 1, 300, 1}]
```

reveals that the threshold opacity is 1/255. (At least this is the case on Windows 7 x64).

At any `WindowOpacity` less than 1/255 the click-through occurs. It seems likely that the window opacity is stored in an 8 bit alpha channel and therefore any value less than 1/255 corresponds to perfect transparency. Presumably the click-through is the default behaviour for fully transparent windows.